# How to make the auto search function work in all new columns?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I am try to make a GUI. I need to add a search function to all new tabs, but I don't understand how this can be done in PySimpleGUI.

This is my code so far:

```
import keyword
import PySimpleGUI as sg

keywords = ['Azocompound','Aloin',"Quercetin"]
font = ('Helvetica', 16)

keys = []

def tab(i):
    return [[sg.Text(f'Choose ligand',font=font)], [sg.Input('', size=(20, 1), font=font,       enable_events=True, key=f'-IN-{i}')],
    [sg.Listbox(values=[], size=(20, 3), enable_events=True, key=f'-BOX-{i}', font=font,  select_mode=sg.LISTBOX_SELECT_MODE_SINGLE)]]

index=5

tabgroup = [[sg.Tab(f'Tab {i}' if i < index -1 else '+', tab(i), key=f'Ligand {i}') for i in     range(index)]]

layout = [[sg.Text('Input Python keyword:', font=font)],
           [sg.TabGroup(tabgroup, key='TabGroup', font=font)],
   [sg.Submit('Start', font=font),sg.Cancel(font=font)]
]

window = sg.Window('AutoComplete', layout, finalize=True)
window['TabGroup'].bind('<<NotebookTabChanged>>', '+Switch')

while True:

    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event == 'TabGroup+Switch':
        i = int(values['TabGroup'].split(' ')[1])
        if i == index-1:
            window[f'Tab {i}'].update(title=f'Tab {i}')
            window['TabGroup'].add_tab(sg.Tab('+', tab(index), key=f'Tab {index}'))
            index += 1  
    for j in range(index):  
        if event == f'-IN-{j}':
                text = values[f'-IN-{j}']
                lst = []
                if text:
                    lst = [item for item in keywords if item.startswith(text)]
                window[f'-BOX-{j}'].update(values=lst)
        elif event == f'-BOX-{j}':   
                window[f'-IN-{j}'].update(value=values[f'-BOX-{j}'])


window.close()
```

I tried adding an iteration over the index species, but when I added a new tab, the GUI broke.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite Python forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.

Answer (score 0):

There're bugs in your script, and here, I find a PySimpleGUI bug by your code.

IMO, this PySimpleGUI bug will be fixed soon, refer https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/issues/6645

Updated code - Find the comments for bugs.

```py
    elif event == 'TabGroup+Switch':
        i = int(values['TabGroup'].split(' ')[1])
        if i == index-1:

            # Wrong Tab key used
            window[f'Ligand {i}'].update(title=f'Tab {i}')

            # Wrong Tab key setting
            window['TabGroup'].add_tab(sg.Tab('+', tab(index), key=f'Ligand {index}'))

            # Add this line to avoid the PySimpleGUI bug
            window['TabGroup'].tab_index_to_key[index] = f'Ligand {index}'

            index += 1
```